Word order of 1 Corinthians 1:24
I saw that the greek of the latter half of 1 Corinthians 1:24 is:
"Χριστὸν Θεοῦ δύναμιν καὶ Θεοῦ σοφίαν."
The direct word for word translation would be "Christ God power and God wisdom".
Why is 1 Corinthians 1:24 typically translated as
(ESV):

"but to those who are called, both Jews and Greeks, Christ the power
of God and the wisdom of God."

And not "Christ of God's power and of God's wisdom."
I suspect that this is because only Θεοῦ (God) appears in the genitive andδύναμιν (power) or σοφίαν (wisdom) do not appear in the genitive, but I am not sure and would like some clarification.

In the phrase in 1 Cor 1:24 -

Χριστὸν Θεοῦ δύναμιν καὶ Θεοῦ σοφίαν

The words, Christ, power, wisdom are in the accusative.  God is genitive both times and so must be translated as "of God".
Therefore, if Paul wanted to say, "Christ of God's power", the word "power" would also need to be genitive or at least dative.  As it is, because Christ, power and wisdom are all in the accusative, power and wisdom must be in apposition to "Christ".  Thus, the only way to accurately translate this phrase is:

Christ [the] power of God and [the] wisdom of God.

The word order in Greek is far less important, on occasions, irrelevant; unlike English where word order is crucial:  there is big difference in English between "Man bites dog" vs "Dog bites man".  In Greek such a reversal would carry the same meaning as the noun cases are built into the words so there is no confusion.

This is kind of what I suspected, but I just wanted to make sure. Thanks! +1
